# Renaming third level directories to be same name

Tags: rename

I have a directory A, which contains a hundred sub-directories. Each one of these sub-directories contains a single directory.

How can I rename this single directory inside of each of the hundred directories to be the same name, say `X`? I have tried the `mmv` command, with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a better way, but:

Using `bash` and `find`

```bsh
while IFS= read -r dir; do
    mv -- "$dir" "${dir%/*}/X"
done< <(find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d)
```

DO a test run first with something like:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r dir; do
    printf 'mv "%s" "%s"\n' "$dir" "${dir%/*}/X"
done< <(find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d)
```

---

In short:

- `find`

  - `.` current directory as base (Typically `A` in your case)
  - `type d` (directory) at minimum and maximum depth of 2
- `bash` read `$dir` from `find` and move `$dir` to

  - `${dir%/*}` remove last `/` and everything there after

    - `/X` append the new directory name.

Use for example `find ./A ...` if you reside one level below A etc.

Optionally add `-v` to `mv` (non-POSIX) to show actions taken.